# WSO2 APIM How can I change Key Manager for try out console

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I have Configured WSO2 Identity Server as a Key Manager successfully. But I couldn't find a way to **set WSO2-IS as Key Manager for try-out console** in Dev portal. It says "The Resident Key Manager is selected for try out console".

Can I set WSO2-IS as Key Manager for try out console?

[image]

What I have tried (With no success):

1. In Runtime Configurations for API, only Allow WSO2-IS as key manager (from publisher portal)
2. Disable "Resident Key Manager" from admin portal

I'm using API-M 3.2.0 & IS 5.11.0

Comment: Did you follow the instructions as mentioned in this [doc](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/key-managers/configure-wso2is-connector/) ?

Comment: @Sarangan Yes, I followed those instructions,  But that Doc has nothing about "change Key Manager for try-out console". Other parts are working as expected. IS configured successfully, I can invoke APIs using those access tokens using external Curl commands. But not inside theTry-out section. I can't change Key Manager for try-out console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are generating the keys, you can select the key manager which is configured on the topmost level of the form. This has been mentioned in other docs.

For example, when configuring **okta** as a KM you need to select **okta** and [generate keys](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/key-managers/configure-okta-connector/#step-3-generate-keys-using-the-okta-key-manager).

Same as above select WSO2-IS as the Key manager and generate Tokens.

**EDIT**

You need to [configure](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/configuring-wso2-identity-server-as-a-key-manager/) it as a [connector](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/key-managers/configure-okta-connector/#step-3-generate-keys-using-the-okta-key-manager) and disable the resident KM for the API. Then try out page will pick the third party KM.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, But my issue is only about "Try out page" (see the screenshot). I want to "Change KM for try out page"

Comment: All other steps are completed (configure KM, generate Tokens using new KM, invoke APIs using those tokens from external cUrl commands working as expected ). But cUrl commands available in "Try out"  page still connected to the "Resident Key Manager". So valid Tokens from IS are still failing inside built-in cUrl consoles in "Try out page"

Comment: Edited the answer :)

Comment: @PradeepalSudeshana were you able to change Key Manager for the "Try Out" block? If yes, could you post your answer ??

Comment: @Iam8139 Unfortunately I did not succeed.